# Receiving data from webhook in chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I'm developing a chrome extension that monitors the live stream on twitch. Currently I make regular calls to the twitch api but this method is not very optimized. With this, my service worker stops working after a while. I am using manifest 2 with the script option persist and a setInterval to restart my request every 2 minutes.

So I would like to use the twitch webhook to wake up my service worker and run a script. Unfortunately I have no idea how to do it.

I don't see which event to use

Here is my code:

```
chrome.runtime.onInstalled.addListener(()=>{
  var notificationSend = false;
  try {
    fetch(chrome.runtime.getURL('../init/data.json'))
      .then((resp) => resp.json())
      .then(function(jsonData) {
        try {
          fetch("https://id.twitch.tv/oauth2/token?client_id=" + jsonData.twitch.TwitchClientId + "&client_secret=" + jsonData.twitch.TwitchSecretId + "&grant_type=client_credentials", {
              method: "POST",
              headers: {
                "Content-Type": "application/json",
                "Accept": "application/json"
              }
            })
            .then((resultToken) => {
              if (!resultToken.ok) {
                throw Error(resultToken.statusText)
              }
              return resultToken.json()
            })
            .then(function(jsonResultToken) {
              try {
                fetch("https://api.twitch.tv/helix/streams?user_id=" + jsonData.twitch.id, {
                    method: "GET",
                    headers: {
                      "client-id": "xxxxxxxx",
                      "Authorization": "Bearer " + jsonResultToken.access_token
                    }
                  })
                  .then((resultWebSocket) => {
                    if (!resultWebSocket.ok) {
                      throw Error(response.statusText)
                    }
                    return resultWebSocket.json()
                  })
                  .then(function(jsonResultWebSocket) {
                    if(jsonResultWebSocket.data.length > 0){
                      if (!notificationSend) {
                        chrome.notifications.onClicked.addListener(function(){
                          chrome.tabs.create({url: "https://www.twitch.tv/"+jsonData.twitch.ChannelId})
                        })
                        chrome.notifications.create("isLive", {
                        })
                        notificationSend = true;
                      }
                    }else{
                      notificationSend = false;
                    }
                  })
                }
                catch (error) {
                  console.log(error)
                }
              })
          }
        catch (err) {
          console.log(err)
        }
        setInterval(function(){
          try {
            fetch("https://id.twitch.tv/oauth2/token?client_id=" + jsonData.twitch.TwitchClientId + "&client_secret=" + jsonData.twitch.TwitchSecretId + "&grant_type=client_credentials", {
                method: "POST",
                headers: {
                  "Content-Type": "application/json",
                  "Accept": "application/json"
                }
              })
              .then((resultToken) => {
                if (!resultToken.ok) {
                  throw Error(resultToken.statusText)
                }
                return resultToken.json()
              })
              .then(function(jsonResultToken) {
                try {
                  fetch("https://api.twitch.tv/helix/streams?user_id=" + jsonData.twitch.id, {
                      method: "GET",
                      headers: {
                        "client-id": "xxxxxx",
                        "Authorization": "Bearer " + jsonResultToken.access_token
                      }
                    })
                    .then((resultWebSocket) => {
                      if (!resultWebSocket.ok) {
                        throw Error(response.statusText)
                      }
                      return resultWebSocket.json()
                    })
                    .then(function(jsonResultWebSocket) {
                      if(jsonResultWebSocket.data.length > 0){
                        if (!notificationSend) {
                          chrome.notifications.onClicked.addListener(function(){
                            chrome.tabs.create({url: "https://www.twitch.tv/"+jsonData.twitch.ChannelId})
                          })
                          chrome.notifications.create("isLive", {
                          })
                          notificationSend = true;
                        }
                      }else{
                        notificationSend = false;
                      }
                    })
                  }
                catch (error) {
                  console.log(error)
                }
              })
            }
          catch (err) {
            console.log(err)
          }
        },120000)
      })
    }
  catch (er) {
    console.log(er)
  }
})
```

Comment: Maybe the alarm API is something which you could use instead https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/alarms/ ?

Comment: You can't use Webhooks. Webhooks required a Web Accessable server to send Post data to. A Chrome Browser extension doesn't provide a HTTP server to have data Posted to